# Basket IF arguments ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, if-statement, checkout

I am developing a rails app that includes a checkout basket and am in need of some basic help.

I am struggling to integrate the logical arguments needed for some product pricing. What I would like to do is lower the price of the product if there are five or more products added to the cart.

I currently have models and controllers for products, line_items, carts and orders with the typical associations.

I am sure there is a simple `if and elseif` statement that I can define in a method but I would be interested to know how others else would go about implementing this as best practice?

Thanks in advance for your help! Elle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure when you're working with a `Cart` versus an `Order`. Let's assume you're mostly working in `Cart` which has a many-to-many relationship to `LineItems`.  At some point, I guess, the `Cart` becomes an order when the user enters their credit card number.

1. First I would say that `Lineitem` should have a `discounted` field. So `LineItem` doesn't necessarily store the discounted price; you let the `Order` or `Cart` class determine it's actual final price.
2. Second use and association callback to automatically apply the discount when a line item gets added to the order.

   ```
   class Cart
     has_many :line_items, 
         after_add: :calculate_volume_discount,   
         after_remove: :calculate_volume_discount

     # When a line item is added or removed determine if current items
     # are entitled to a discount
     def calculate_volume_discount line_item
       current_count = line_items.count
       line_items.each do |li|
         li.discounted = (current_count >= 5)
         li.save
       end  
     end
   end
   ```